# how to create a variable-template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variable-templates

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<int base, int x>
struct Power {


    static constexpr int a = base * (Power<base, x - 1>::a);

};

template<int base>
struct Power<base, 0> {


static constexpr int a = 1;

};
```

/////////////////////////////////    I failed in creating a variable-template here.

```
template<int base, int x>       
using power_v = typename Power<base, x>::a;
```

/////////////////////////////////

```
int main()
{
    constexpr int y = power_v<3, 2>;

    cout << y;
}
```

Comment: `using power_v = typename ...` creates a type alias, not a variable. Use `inline constexpr int power_v = ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`using` is used for declaring [type alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias).

> Type alias is a name that refers to a previously defined type (similar
>   to [typedef](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef)).
>
> Alias template is a name that refers to a family of types.

As [variable_template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template) it should be

```
template<int base, int x>       
constexpr int power_v = Power<base, x>::a;
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5gGC5s8k192NdHWC)